# How to stop a process from starting using a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, process

I've been trying to find a way to stop a process from starting using a batch file. So far I've had no success.

I know I can use `taskkill` to kill a process that's already running, but I want to stop it  from starting in the first place.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you expand on what "stop a process from starting using cmd" means?

Comment: If you wanted to stop the process procexp64.exe from launching, you could run: `reg.exe add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\procexp64.exe" /v Debugger /t REG_SZ "null"` This will prevent the process from starting.

Comment: @HelpingHand That is a really good answer. Why not write it as such?

Comment: @HelpingHand I apologize, what I meant was using a batch file. I was wondering if it's possible to write a batch file that blocks a process from starting, in a similar fashion to Software Restriction Policies.

Comment: @Frdcrls You do realize that the contents of a batch file are commands which get executed in sequence in the windows shell?

Comment: @mashuptwice Yes, I am aware of that.

Comment: So you do realize that you could take @HelpingHand command and put it in a batch file?